# CMD - If else modulo

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, windows-7, modulo

I'm struggeling with using the If-Else Command with the Modulo-Operator (Windows 7 CommandLine)

I would like using a command only every hour. My Batch pings out every minute , and the store the "Result" in the **"myIP.csv"**-File

My Batch looks like this.

```
@echo off
set COUNTER=0

:AGAIN
set TimeVar=%time:~0,8%
for /f "skip=4 tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com') do (set IP=%%a)
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('ping -n 2 8.8.8.8') do (set ANSWER=%%b)
echo %date%,%TimeVar%,%IP%,%ANSWER:~0,-1%; >> myIP_newOne.txt
SET /A COUNTER+=1
timeout 60
goto AGAIN
```

It should look something like this

```
@echo off
SET COUNTER=0
SET HOUR=60

:AGAIN
SET /a DOIT=COUNTER%%HOUR
IF %DOIT% === 0 (
    CODEBLOCK-A... 
    CODEBLOCK-B...
) ELSE (
    CODEBLOCK-A
)
timeout 60
goto AGAIN
```

I tried several different methods, but i can't make it work. I would like to use the "GetIP"-Command only once per hour... not every minute.
Perhabs i just have some "bad formatting" in it. Not sure why it won't work.

I'll hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: in the Batch i posted above... it stores the Result in myIP_newOne.txt, not myIP.csv as i told. (Sorry... copy-paste mistake)

Comment: Why not just use the Windows scheduler and have it run once per hour?

Comment: I have huge Problems with my ISP. I get interrupts all the time, so i made this little Batch-File that writes a CSV-File (Log-File). So i have something i can show them (ISP). And i just wanted that it updates every hour my external IP. It should be a Batch-File, cause i'm not a big Fan of the Scheduler. I should be one Batch-File

Comment: If you want it to run once an hour, why not just write it to _work_, and then set it up in the Task Scheduler to run once an hour?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The Batch pings out every Minute and stores the Result in a File(Log), but every hour it should update my External-IP. Now it works

Comment: Is there some particular reason for that? If you really need to ping-and-log every minute, why not make that a separate process from the once-an-hour process?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The only reason was to achieve it in one Batch-File, a little Challenge for me. But i couldn't make it without help. It would be possible with 2 File's (processes), but i want it in one. (i'm a stubborn head)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "minute=0"

:loop
IF "%minute%"=="60" (
    COMMAND A
    COMMAND B
    SET "minute=0"
) ELSE (
    COMMAND A
)

PING -n 61 127.0.0.1>nul
SET /A "minute=%minute%+1"
GOTO loop
```

Use `PING` instead, it consumes less processor time ([read more](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)).

Comment: Thx a lot... i missed the second % which destroyed all... It works now

Comment: Oups... made a very similar error in the IF-statement... fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF %DOIT% === 0 (
```

should be

```
IF %DOIT% == 0 (
```

(two `=`, not 3)

Comment: thanks @Magoo, i still have to learn a lot. But now i know how to work with the Modulo and other Variants. I like stackoverflow a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. 4 eyes sees more than 2 :-)

Here is my complete Code (which hopefully works now & forever)

EDIT:
If you want to use Modulo, you'll **NEED** two **%**

**HERE is the Code WITH Modulo**

```
@echo off
SET /A minute=0
SET /A hour=60

:LOOP
SET TimeVar=%time:~0,8%
SET /A DOIT=minute%%hour
IF %DOIT% == 0 (
    for /f "skip=4 tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com') do (set IP=%%a)
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('ping -n 2 8.8.8.8') do (set ANSWER=%%b)
    echo "MODULO WORKS"
) ELSE (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('ping -n 2 8.8.8.8') do (set ANSWER=%%b)
)
echo %date%,%TimeVar%,%IP%,%ANSWER:~0,-1%; >> myIP.csv
PING -n 61 127.0.0.1>nul
SET /A minute=%minute%+1
REM echo %minute%
goto LOOP
```

**Simple Modulo-Example** fast Edition

```
@echo off
SET /A minute=0
SET /A hour=60

:LOOP
SET /A DOIT=minute%%hour
IF %DOIT% == 0 (
    echo "CodeBlock-A & CodeBlock-B"
) ELSE (
    echo "CodeBlock-A"
)

PING -n 1 127.0.0.1>nul
SET /A minute=%minute%+1
goto LOOP
```

Comment: Astonishing! `IF "minute"=="60" ` will *always* be false, since the two string `minute` and `60` will *always* be different. Now `IF "%minute%"=="60" (` - now that's different, nd has a chance of working.

Comment: @Magoo That was my mistake from the solution, fixed it now... I keep forgetting `%` in IF-statements... ._.

Comment: I'm lucky that i'm not the only one who makes mistakes. But again... thank you all for your help. It finally works like i wanted to.